# How to create a structure that holds a function with arbitrary arity in scala

Tags: scala

I need a way to hold an function with an arbitrary number of arguments, from 1 to 22. Something like:

```
case class Function[A,B](operation: A => B, name: String)
```

I want to generalize the operation: `(A, A, .. ) => B`

My first attempt was to create multiple factories in the companion object like:

```
object Function {
  def apply[A, B](name: String)(op: Function1[A, B]) =
    new Function[A, B]("name") {
      val operation = op
    }

  def apply[A, B](name: String)(op: Function2[A, A, B]) =
    new Function[A, B]("name") {
      val operation = op
    }

  // ...

}
```

However i wasn't able to put this working and it is too much messy.

I was wondering what is the correct way of providing a solution to this problem?

I also cannot create a trait `trait Function[A,B]` because if i turn `operator` into a field of `Function`, the type system would force me to provide a type, thus iimpossibliting the use of `Function` to accept a `FunctionN`.

I have been reading some hints pointing to Shapaless. Is this the only way? I didn't want to introduce a new dependency in my library.

Comment: You don't have to use Shapeless, but you will almost certainly have to recreate the kind of boilerplate that Shapeless provides. This could be more or less minimal depending on what you're trying to accomplish, which isn't really clear from the question.

Comment: i just needed a way to "hold" an arbitrary function.

imagine that i have a trait `AnyFunction`. i could than receive as argument any subclass of this trait `Function1, Function2, ... `

imagine a function like

`def applyFunction[A,B](f: AnyFunction[A,B], args: List[A])`